# Не передается JSTL выражение в функцию JS через onclick

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Я передаю параметр с помощью JSTL выражения в функцию JS

```
<c:if test="${product.inStock==1}">
         <a id = "product_'${product.id}'/>" class="btn btn-success btn-lg buy_btn" onclick="javascript:addToCart('${product.id}')"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Buy </a>
</c:if>
```

Вот сама функция:

```
 function addToCart (productid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url:  "http://" + $(location).attr('host') + "/add-to-cart/" +productid
    });
    }
```

Проблема в том, что в моем JSP `${product.id}` внутри `onclick` не возвращает текущее значение поля объекта, а всегда возвращает ноль:

[image: всегда возвращает ноль]

При этом в других частях JSP `${product.id}` как и нужно возвращает фактическое значение поля `id` объекта `product`. В чем может быть проблема?

Если заменить через консоль `0` на нужное значение поля `id`, запрос от Ajax попадает в контроллер и тот его правильно обрабатывает. Вопрос в том, почему `${product.id}` не хочет передаваться через `onclick`?

Answer (score 1):

Данное выражение `${product.id}` выполняется на сервере. Если оно возвращает там значение то оно должно везде. Убедитесь что у вас установлен JSP двигатель и на странице разрешено использовать EL выражения. То что вы смотрите в браузере - это DOM.

Значение DOM может отличаться от результата, сгенерированного на сервере. Для того, чтобы узнать значение возвращаемое на сервере, вам надо использовать отладчик или можно вывести значение напрямую в `out`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Проблема решена!